# Liquibase insert from old database into new schema

Tags: mysql, liquibase

I have a database user with access to 2 schemas, oldDb and newDb and I want to select everything from `oldDb.users` table and insert them into `newDb.users` using Liquibase.

I want to be able to not to hard code the schema names because I want to test the code locally and in different test environments before running it on real data, and in test environments the names of the schemas are different. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

One high level way might be to run

liquibase generateChangeLog

against oldDB to pull out the table.
Then do a global replace of the oldDB. schema name with the new schema name newDB.
A second option would be to do the global replace of oldDB. with a ${replaceSchema}
and then add a property to your changelog called replaceSchema or at runtime provide the parameter.

More details here
https://docs.liquibase.com/concepts/changelogs/property-substitution.html